# How to pass value from collection view to table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am displaying below data in collection view.

And my JSON data is like:

```
data {

type : max
id  : 1234

type : vete
id : 3445

type : tomoe
id : 2220

type : matye
id : 9087

}
```

Same like each type have some data like for example:

**Type: max
id: 1234**

This above type have:

```
[
{
name : max 1
description : masncj

name : max 1
description : masncj


name : max 2
description : masncj


name : max 3
description : masncj


name : max 4
description : masncj


}
]
```

And I am displaying the above data name, description in table view.

Now what I need is, when ever I click any data type name like max, vete, tomoe, etc. In collection view.

I need to redirect to table view as push segue and in that table view I need to display the respective data.

Like if I press max type name cell in collection view - then it have to redirect to table view and there I need to populate max1, description.

I need to use one collection view and one table view controller for this.

How can I pass the type id and how can I see the respective data - when I press any data in collection view - I need to shoe that respective data names, description in table view?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create a segue from CollectionViewVC to TableViewVC using Storyboard and give it a identifier  name something like "collection_to_table".

Create a variable name typeId in both the View controller as

```
var typeId = ""
```

Now in CollectionViewVC On click on type , perform this

```
typeId = <actualTypeId> //This is dynamic value from your json   
performSegueWithIdentifier("collection_to_table", sender: self)
```

Now override a method in CollectionViewVC

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
         if segue.identifier == "collection_to_table"
        {
            let secondVC : TableViewVC = segue.destinationViewController as! TableViewVC
            secondVC.typeId = typeId
        }
    }
```

Now You have typeId value in TableView Which you can use to fetch info.

Hope this help you . Let me know if you find it hard to understand .

Comment: Thanks for your solution.But actually in my collection view.swift and in my tableviewcontroller.swift i have to assign `var typeId = ""`..Then in my collection view vc ..on type Id = <actualTypeID> means..I have to display dynamically.Beacuse now i have some 5 data and 5 typ id.So may be that  5 data can chnage to 50 in future know.Then how can i assign the type if value there??

Comment: And also.. i need to show the name, description based on the click action of my cell in collection view...so by this perform seague ....can i also show the name, description .....when i click any cell name??

Comment: On collection view click you will have the position of the view. From that position you can assign a id to that typeId variable. You must have a list of type ? . Can you tell me how are you feeding data to collection view?

Comment: as nsurl connection from one base url

Comment: No I mean after getting Json what are you doing with it ?

Comment: after getting json data i will display the type name like `max, vete,..` in collection view..So after that when  i press any cell in colelction view i need to show the data in table view with respective details...As per i mention in my post

Comment: I mean to say you must have been using a List of max , vete , ... etc . to feed data in collection view .

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var tblview: UITableView!

    var fruit = ["tomato","mango","orange","banana","apple"]

    var fruitsimg : NSMutableArray = ["tomato_small.png","images-1.jpg","fruit-1218149_960_720.png","4164249-fruit-images.jpg","5135668-fruit-images.jpg",]





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, t/Users/agile-14/Desktop/4164249-fruit-images.jpgypically from a nib.


    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 20

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 20
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)
    {
        view.tintColor = UIColor.red


    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {


        view.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return fruit[section]

    }





    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruit.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as! TableViewCell1

        cell.lbl1.text = fruit[indexPath.row]
        cell.img1.image = UIImage(named: fruitsimg[indexPath.row] as! String)
        cell.img1.layer.cornerRadius = cell.img1.layer.frame.height / 2

        cell.img1.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.img1.layer.borderWidth = 2
        cell.img1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        var vc1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "collViewController") as! collViewController
        vc1.arr = fruitsimg
        //vc1.str = fruitsimg[indexPath.row]


        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc1, animated: true)

    }
```

2.

```
class collViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet var coll: UICollectionView!
    var arr : NSMutableArray = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return arr.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = coll.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as! CollectionViewCell1

        cell.img2.image = UIImage(named: arr[indexPath.row] as! String)

        return cell

    }
```